# Angular Storing array into Cookie

Tags: angularjs

I have a function below that works fine and passes info into and retrieves from a cookieStore without issue

```
            $scope.num = 0
            $scope.nums = []

            $scope.increment = function () {
                $scope.num++
            }
            $scope.$watch('num', function () {
                $scope.nums.push($scope.num)
            })
            $scope.storeProductsInCookie=function(){
                $cookieStore.put("invoices",$scope.nums)
            };
            $scope.getProductsInCookie=function(){
                console.log(  $cookieStore.get("invoices",$scope.nums));
            }
```

However when I try with the below verufyGuess function that is injecting the Index and no as parameters into the function it fails to place into the cookieStore

$scope.verifyGuess = function (Index , no) {

```
                $scope.votes = {};
                $scope.newVotes = []

                 $scope.votes[Index] = $scope.votes[Index] || 0;
                 $scope.votes[Index]+= no;

                $scope.$watch('votes', function () {
                    $scope.newVotes.push($scope.votes)
                })
                $scope.storeProductsInCookie=function(){
                    $cookieStore.put("invoices",$scope.newVotes)
                };
                $scope.getProductsInCookie=function(){
                    console.log(   $cookieStore.get("invoices",$scope.newVotes));
                }
```

Comment: Fail occurs at this line $cookieStore.put("invoices",$cope.newVotes) ?

Comment: please expand elaborate on your answer

Answer (score 0):

`$cookieStore` is Deprecated: (since v1.4.0)
Please use the `$cookies` service instead.

`$scope.nums` is an array of strings.So `$cookieStore` is storing them as string(cookies only support strings to store).

In second case `$scope.newVotes` is an array of objects. cookies wont store objects.

you must use `$cookieStore.put("invoices", JSON.stringify($scope.newVotes))`

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.12/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.12/angular-cookies.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <script>
    var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ngCookies']);

    app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $cookies) {

      $scope.votes = {};
      $scope.newVotes = []
      var Index = 0;
      $scope.votes[Index] = $scope.votes[Index] || 0;
      $scope.votes[Index] += 10;


      $scope.newVotes.push($scope.votes)

      $scope.storeProductsInCookie = function() {
        $cookies.put("invoices", JSON.stringify($scope.newVotes))
      };
      $scope.getProductsInCookie = function() {
        console.log($cookies.get("invoices"));
      }

      $scope.storeProductsInCookie();
      $scope.getProductsInCookie();

    });
  </script>
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: I add and get cookie It's returning   [{"9":1}] then I page refresh and again  add and get cookie  and it brings back [{"10":1}]     The result I'm after is   [{"9":1}{"10":1}]  and append to the previous result